# Phonegap Currency Converter Web Service

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, cordova

I'm new to phonegap and I wanted to develop an app which consumes the web service from the link below using SOAP. I hope someone could guide me to get the web service working as I have been searching for examples but it does not work out.

http://currencyconverter.kowabunga.net/converter.asmx?op=GetConversionAmount

Comment: http://www.xe.com/faq/tools_linktosite.php please refer this link

Comment: @Piyush i wished to use the SOAP message to communicate with the web service of the given link.